# Rspec controller basic test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm working on a ruby on rails project (rails 3.2.12 and ruby 1.9.3) and I'm trying to test one of my controllers. So, I have this controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

and my test:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe PostsController do
  let(:post){FactoryGirl.create(:post)}
    context "JSON" do
      describe "GET #index" do
        it "should access index" do
           get :index
        end
      end
   end
end
```

and my routes.rb

```
 AuthApp::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :posts
 end
```

but after run

```
$ rspec spec
```

I got this error:

```
1) PostsController JSON GET #index should access index
     Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template posts/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
         * "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0x007fbfb62d64a0>"
     # ./spec/controllers/post_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can access to /posts with index action instead of /posts/index?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The example is incomplete yet. What to test? Be patient to write full example at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers. The problem I had was that my template was a jbuilder template and spec doesn't render them by default.

I was fixed using this [link](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/32) in github.

Comment: The problem is the naming of the view file. `index.jbuilder` can be rendered, `index.json.jbuilder` can't.

Answer (score 4):

By default, rspec is configured not to render the views ([see here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/configuration.rb#L71)) 
It can be changed in spec/support/spec_helper.rb (or spec/support/rails_helper.rb) like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config| 
  config.render_views = true 
end
```

or the block can be added in the spec files where needed:

```
require 'rails_helper' 

RSpec.configure do |config| 
  config.render_views = true 
end 

describe SessionsController, :type => :controller do 
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the format as json

```
it "........" do
 expected = {...}.to_json
 get :index, :format => :json
 response.body.should == expected
end
```